# Что обычно делают, когда у человека к тебе персональная неприязнь?

Tags: обсуждение, модерация, тревоги

Случилось так, что человек "невзлюбил" тебя и при этом всячески пытается писать кляузы модераторам по любой допустимой причине, дай только повод. Лично мне ровно, я его знать не знаю. У кого что было и как поступили?

Comment: Если причина действительно допустима, то всё нормально. Если же нет, то модераторы отклонят тревогу (если это понимается под "кляузой"). Думаю, что при определённом количестве отклонённых тревог дальнейшая возможность их посылать автоматически блокируется

Comment: Причина есть, но скажем так не очень грубая, высосанная из пальца скажем так, а если учитывать что это личное то становится всё понятно

Comment: Не припомню конкретно на вас никаких "кляуз" )

Comment: Значит, это до модераторов не дошло, потому что и я не помню. Разве что ЮраСПб? Да и аналогичный случай был давно уже... месяца полтора назад, не меньше.

Comment: _Лично мне ровно, я его знать не знаю_ - абсолютно правильная реакция. Пока вам не написали модераторы, игнорировать, никак не поступать, ничего не делать. Если действия "недоброжелателя" перешли границы "просто кляузы", например, недружелюбные комментарии, массовое минусование, то вешать тревогу или сообщить модераторам.